# Merge Arry for sitemap & implode

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sitemap, array-merge

I use implode '/' but in this case,
I want, the last 2 columns `iid` & `branch_id` like ==>>>> `iid."_".branch_id` I mean for last 2 columns implode will be '_' underscore not '/' slash, but for the first 4 columns it'll be /, only for the last two columns it'll be underscore. Please help me with proper solution. Thanks

```
echo "Creating Sitemap\n";
$switzerland= new Sitemap($switzerlandcodes_sitefile,["name","canton","city","iid","branch_id"],"UNKNOWN", $homeUrl.SWITZERLANDPATH.'/', SWITZERLANDTABLE);
$switzerland->createSitemap();
$files=array_merge($files,$switzerland->files);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the example you **don't show us your data** or **how you use the *implode* function** but based on the text of your question, I would put it this way:

- `array_chunk` by length of 3 (name, canton, city) to *split* array into *base* array and *param* array
- `implode` *base* by `/`
- `implode` *param* by `_`
- concat it together with `/`

```php
$data = ['SomeName', 'Canton', 'AnotherCity', 'SomeIID', 'SomeBranchID'];
[$base, $param] = array_chunk($data, 3);
$result = implode('/',$base).'/'.implode('_',$param);
```

result is

```
SomeName/Canton/AnotherCity/SomeIID_SomeBranchID
```